# Package sp : coordinates function error no numeric matrix

Tags: coordinates, sp

I am trying to use coordinates function from sp package to transform my data in spatial data. I made sure I deleted all the NAs values and that all my data is numeric, however, i still get the same error.
I have checked in the package information about negative values, but it seems should not be the problem

```
require(adegenet)
require(pegas)       
require(sp)
require(PopGenReport)
require(dplyr)
require(poppr)

Sites.sp <- Locations
SitesNA.sp<-subset(Sites.sp,!(is.na(Sites.sp["Latitude"]) | 
is.na(Sites.sp["Longitude"])))


coordinates(SitesNA.sp) <- ~Latitude+Longitude
as.tibble(SitesNA.sp)
```

> coordinates(SitesNA.sp) <- ~Latitude+Longitude
>   Error in .local(obj, ...) : 
>     cannot derive coordinates from non-numeric matrix

[image]

dput

> `structure(list(`A/A`= c(NA, NA, 174, 173, 164, 152), YEAR = c("2016", 
>   "2016", "2014", "2014", "2013", NA), Collector = c("P. Carazo", 
>   "P. Carazo", "AubretTeam", "AubretTeam", "UllerTeam", "AubretTeam"
>   ), Population = c("Istria, Pula", "Cres Island, Cres Township", 
>   "Ile d'Yeu Saint-sauveur", "Ile d'Yeu Port Joinville", "Vitre", 
>   "Taurignan Vieux"), Country = c("Croatia", "Croatia", "FR", "FR", 
>   "FR", "FR"), Abbreviation = c("Pula", "Cres Township", "YSS", 
>   "YPJ", "VR", "TV"), Latitude = c("44.849504000000003", "44.959245000000003", 
>   "46.706412999999998", "46.727950499999999", "48.124009999999998", 
>   "43.0276"), Longitude = c("13.849347", "14.404019999999999", 
>   "-2.3309148999999998", "-2.3523725999999998", "-1.2143999999999999", 
>   "1.1152"), Altitude = c(NA, NA, "NA", "NA", "91", "NA"), No.Samples = c("3", 
>   "3", "34", "No samples sent", "20", "30"), X__1 = c(NA, NA, NA, 
>   NA, "Geoff to confirm exact location", NA)), .Names = c("A/A", 
>   "YEAR", "Collector", "Population", "Country", "Abbreviation", 
>   "Latitude", "Longitude", "Altitude", "No.Samples", "X__1"), row.names = c(NA, 
>   -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))`

Comment: But `SitesNA` is not the same than `SitesNA.sp`. This kind of code isn't object-oriented, so `.sp` is not an attribute or method of `SitesNA`

Comment: ado_tapia sorry it was a typo when writing it here, but that is not the problem :) thanks

Comment: Can you add `dput(head(SitesNA))` to trying to reproduce the problem?

Comment: The answer is certainly that your lat/long data are character but, please look at your workflow as well. It makes very little sense that you are coercing the data to a SpatialPointsDataFrame and then turning it into a tribble, which is no longer a spatial class object. Although, there may be capacity to handle tribble classes as simple features, I just don't know.

Answer (score 3):

Look the image uploaded by you, also check the data:

```r
dplyr::glimpse(SitesNA)
## Observations: 6
## Variables: 11
## $ `A/A`        <dbl> NA, NA, 174, 173, 164, 152
## $ YEAR         <chr> "2016", "2016", "2014", "2014", "2013", NA
## $ Collector    <chr> "P. Carazo", "P. Carazo", "AubretTeam", "AubretTeam", "UllerTea...
## $ Population   <chr> "Istria, Pula", "Cres Island, Cres Township", "Ile d'Yeu Saint-...
## $ Country      <chr> "Croatia", "Croatia", "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR"
## $ Abbreviation <chr> "Pula", "Cres Township", "YSS", "YPJ", "VR", "TV"
## $ Latitude     <chr> "44.849504000000003", "44.959245000000003", "46.706412999999998...
## $ Longitude    <chr> "13.849347", "14.404019999999999", "-2.3309148999999998", "-2.3...
## $ Altitude     <chr> NA, NA, "NA", "NA", "91", "NA"
## $ No.Samples   <chr> "3", "3", "34", "No samples sent", "20", "30"
## $ X__1         <chr> NA, NA, NA, NA, "Geoff to confirm exact location", NA
```

`Latitude` and `Longitude` are character, so convert them and `coordinates()` will work:

```r
SitesNA$Latitude <- as.numeric(SitesNA$Latitude)
SitesNA$Longitude <- as.numeric(SitesNA$Longitude)

coordinates(SitesNA) <- ~Latitude + Longitude
```

Comment: @MaravillasRuiz you welcome. The manner to say *thank you* in this site is accepting the answer. Cheers

Comment: In this case 'as.numeric()' will work however, the R default is characters as factors, which would make 'as.numeric()' not work because it would return the factor level and not the vector value. With coercing a factor to numeric you would need to to do 'as.numeric(as.character(x))'

Comment: @JeffreyEvans exactly. In that case `as.numeric()` could be a headache for new r-users

Comment: I have always found this behavior bizarre. It seems like the default coercion should be returning the values of the vector and there should be a different function for returning the levels of the factor for the entire vector. Historically, this has been argued numerous times but the R core team is insistent that this is the correct way to handle factors.